# The disk read/write rate and cpu usage of cassandra db intermittently bounce

Tags: cassandra

The disk read/write rate and cpu usage of cassandra db intermittently bounce.

Casssandra was installed with docker, and node exporter and process exporter were used for monitoring. Node and process exporter are all installed with Docker.
I checked the process exporter at the time it bounced. The process that consumed the most resources during the bounced time has Java in the groupname. I'm guessing that there might be a problem with cassandra java.

No more special traffic came in at the time of the bounce.
It does not match the compaction cycle.
Clustering is not broken.

cassandra version is 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra 4 you have the ability to access swiss java knife (sjk) via nodetool and one of the things you get access to is ttop.
If you run the following in your cassandra env during the time your cpu is spiking you can see which threads are the top consumers, which then allows you to dial in on those threads specifically to see if there is an actual problem.

```
nodetool sjk ttop >> $(hostname -i)_ttop.out
```

Allow that to run to completion (during a period of reported high cpu), or at least for 5-10min or so if you decide to kill it early.  This will collect a new iteration every few seconds, so once complete, parse the results to see which threads are regularly top consumers and what percentage of the cpu they are actually using, then you'll have a targeted approach at where to troubleshoot for potential problems in the jvm.

If nothing good turns up, go for a thread dump next for a more complete look and I recommend the following script:
https://github.com/brendancicchi/collect-thread-dumps